# How to check multiple condition for string data type using IF statement using && operator

Tags: c#

Anyone please help me, my problem is this 
i want to check in c#, more textbox values conditions using 'if' statement like this,

```
  if(txtbox1.Text == "" && txtbox2.Text == "" && ...&&txtboxN.Text =="")
  {
    MessageBox.Show("Please enter the details");
    return;
  }
```

but when i use more condition it is not taking the 'second' and others conditions..
what is the solution for this?

Comment: Whats the input you are providing. Well if the first condition fails it will not go to second. But I don't know exactly what you are doing here

Comment: Offtopic Hint: do not use == "" statement. Use string.InNullOrEmpty(str) or string.InNullOrWhiteSpace(str)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use **&**, not **&&**.
With **&&** if first condition is false, other conditions are not evaluated at all.
Anyway for your example I think you should use `||`, so if one of textboxes is empty your message is shown.

Comment: @kartik: with `&&` if first condition is false, other conditions are not evaluated at all; with `&` every condition is evaluated, even if first is false. The question is: do you want messagebox to be shown if all three textboxes are empty or if one is empty? If you need the first, use `&`, else use `||`.

Answer (score 10):

It sounds like you want **or** NOT **and** (i.e. swap the `&&` for `||` ).

Comment: @karthik: Welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer solved your question please accept it by clicking on the check mark to its left. Also, please up vote (by clicking the Up arrow above the number tot he left) any useful answers.

Comment: Upvoting is only possible with [15 rep or more](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/vote-up)

Answer (score 5):

I think you want to use OR not AND:

```
if(txtbox1.Text == "" || txtbox2.Text == "" || ...||txtboxN.Text =="")
```

This will show the message box if at least one text box is empty.